# Ruby - adding a directory to $LOAD_PATH - what does it do?

Tags: ruby

This is actually a question about this question: [Adding a directory to $LOAD_PATH (Ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837123/adding-a-directory-to-load-path-ruby)

What happens when you add a directory to the $LOAD_PATH? Is it like adding a script file to the execution context as in JavaScript? (You can access global methods/objects in another files) If not, how do I call the methods of other ruby files in the current directory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you add the `/Users/you/scripts/ruby` directory to the load path, you can use:

```
require 'example'
```

instead of:

```
require '/Users/you/scripts/ruby/example.rb'
```

Comment: We still have to use `require` to include that class in our code. So, Is it okay to say that it only helps to specify the relative path instead of absolute path?

Comment: wished more of the answers were this simple and straightforward. great use of example to explain a concept. kudos @adrian

Answer (score 1):

Think of the `$LOAD_PATH` as to being similar to the `PATH` variable on a operating system. If certain directories are in the LOAD_PATH, you can just write `require "some_module"`. 
It's also the reason for being able to `require` files from the current directory.

By default, the LOAD_PATH no longer includes the current directory `.` having been [removed in Ruby 1.9.2](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2010/08/18/ruby-1-9-2-released/).

Comment: Only in Ruby 1.8. $LOAD_PATH in 1.9 does not include the working directory.

Comment: @Adrian: 1.9.1 has `'.'` in `$LOAD_PATH`.