# Ruby Minitest simple test raise error - wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby, minitest

I'm trying to learn the TDD approach, to do so I'm using pure Ruby app which is responsible for formatting UK phone number. In my class I want to test if the whitespaces and are removed from given phone number. Basically I'm trying to test the Ruby `.delete(' ')` method.

Tested module

```
# lib/formatter/phone_number/uk.rb

module Formatter
  module PhoneNumber
    module Uk
      
      (...)

      def self.format(number)
        number.delete(' ')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The test

```
# test/lib/formater/phone_number/uk_test.rb

require 'minitest/autorun'

class UkTest < Minitest::Test
  test 'remove whitespaces' do
    invalid_number = '+44 12 12 12 12   '
    Formatter::PhoneNumber::Uk.format(invalid_number)

    assert_equal '+4412121212'
  end
end
```

Which give me an error:

> test/lib/formater/phone_number/uk_test.rb:6:in `test': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) (ArgumentError)

Aside from the fact that testing a method built in Ruby is not a good idea, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the exact error that you get?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It's `test/lib/formater/phone_number/uk_test.rb:6:in test': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) (ArgumentError)`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define a test-method (the method name must start with `test_`).

Inside the test method you define your assertions. In your case, you compare the expected value with the result of your method.

```
class UkTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_remove_whitespaces
    invalid_number = '+44 12 12 12 12   '
    assert_equal '+4412121212', Formatter::PhoneNumber::Uk.format(invalid_number)
  end
end
```

Full test in one file:

```
module Formatter
  module PhoneNumber
    module Uk
      def self.format(number)
        number.delete(' ')
      end
    end
  end
end

require 'minitest/autorun'

class UkTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_remove_whitespaces
    invalid_number = '+44 12 12 12 12   '
    assert_equal '+4412121212', Formatter::PhoneNumber::Uk.format(invalid_number)
  end
end
```

---

Same test with `minitest/spec`

```
require 'minitest/spec'
describe Formatter::PhoneNumber::Uk do
  it 'removes spaces from numbers' do
        invalid_number = '+44 12 12 12 12   '
        _(Formatter::PhoneNumber::Uk.format(invalid_number)).must_equal('+4412121212')
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok but why I can't use `test '(...)' do ` syntax ? what does it depend on? BTW your code raise an error `UkTest#test_remove_whitespaces:
NameError: uninitialized constant UkTest::Formatter`

Comment: For the error: Do you load your code in `uk_test.rb`? (Depending on your settings `require uk.rb`  or `require_relative uk.rb`) - I added a full example with the complete code in one file.

Comment: Ok I've to add this file based on a very strange way - `require_relative '../../../../lib/formatter/phone_number/uk'`, is there any workaround to avoid this stupid `../../../../` ?

Comment: Why do you expect the `test '(...)' do`  syntax should work? I may be wrong, but I never saw this syntax in combination with minitest. Maybe it would be worth for you, to take a look to rspec or minitest/spec. I will add a little code example.

Comment: for your `require_relative`-question: It depends on you folder structure. You could also extend the loadpath `$LOAD_PATH` (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177648/ruby-adding-a-directory-to-load-path-what-does-it-do).

Comment: `test ' 'do` is standard syntax for Minitest, nothing related with `minitest/spec` https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#rails-meets-minitest check the section with `test "the truth" do `. I don't know but maybe it works only when Rails is on board - my app is pure Ruby app.

Comment: @mr_muscle Yes, it looks like the `test '...' do ... end` syntax is an extension to minitest that Rails adds.