# Require a ruby file in a ruby file

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want to `require` a file called `config.rb` in a different ruby file called `basics.rb`. I'm using Sinatra as my web framework. I'm sure there's a way to do this, I just can't find anything in the docs.

Hopefully it would look something like

```
post '/' do
  require 'config.rb'
  // logic
end
```

Comment: What directories (relative to the app root) are these in, and how are you running the app? (This info is necessary to understand how your `$LOAD_PATH` is set, which determines how you can require the files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If config.rb is in your load path, you can require it at the top of your basics.rb file with `require 'config'`.  If it is not in your load path, you'll need something like `require '/path/to/your/config'`.

The code you've posted will require the file.  But only when someone POSTs to '/'.

Also, it's normal to omit the .rb extension when requiring ruby files.  But you can include it if you like.

You can view your load path by inspecting the global variable `$LOAD_PATH`.  From the command line `ruby -e 'puts $LOAD_PATH'` will print it for your version of ruby.  You can also [add directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837123/adding-a-directory-to-load-path-ruby) to your load path.

Comment: Cool. I'm just learning ruby. It's amazing how simple everything is! What is my default load path, just so I know?

Comment: Cool.  I'm glad you're enjoying it.  I've amended my answer with a way to view your load path.