# Ruby's counterpart to python 's __init__

Tags: ruby

Python has modules and packages, and packages have `__init__.py` file, so if I import a package called `foo`, the interpreter will look for `foo/__init__.py`.

I came across some ruby code that will include not a module but a directory: `require 'core/utilts'`. The `core` and `utilts` are directories, not single module files. What is the equivalent in ruby to the file `__init__.py`, or what are the files that are executed when I require a directory like this `utilts` dir? There are a lot of ruby files under it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't import directories in Ruby. If you're running `require 'core/utils'`, then there is a **file** called `core/utils.rb`. There might *also* be a directory called `core/utils/` but it's `utils.rb` that is being included via `require`, and it will in turn likely includes files out of `core/utils/`.

So, the answer to your question is: No, there is no equivalent to `foo/__init__.py`, but the same thing can typically be accomplished with `foo.rb` which includes additional files in `foo/`.

Comment: +1 for "there is a file called core/utils.rb." That's the reason it seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

ruby is a little different. Usually gems or "libraries" in ruby modify the LOAD_PATH constant which is where the ruby interpreter looks for files when you call require. So a standard gem works by appending the lib directory to the LOAD_PATH and then files can be required that are namespaced inside that directory. It is also a convention that there is usually a file with the same name as the library that can be required and then loads all dependencies.

For example: with the following project.

```
lib/
 -- core/utils/
 -- core/utils.rb
core_utils.gemspec
```

you would call:

```
require "core/utils"
```

and the utils.rb would load all files within the core/utils path.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby doesn't support loading entire directories, but it's easy to do if need-be:

```
Dir.glob('lib/*.rb').map do |p|
  require p
end
```

I used `map` for this because it'll return the [`require`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require) response, making it possible to see if something failed to load, since `require` returns true for success and false for failure. Failure/false means the file wasn't loaded because it didn't need to be, usually that is because it already had been by something else. If you don't care about the returned values, use `each` instead of `map`.

You could also do the tricks mentioned in "[Adding a directory to $LOAD_PATH (Ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837123/adding-a-directory-to-load-path-ruby)" and then use `require` without any path prefixed to the file you want to load.