# How to run a ruby package installed on an alternative path?

Tags: ruby, macos, macos-mojave

I want to build and try out this github project https://github.com/cmedley/terraforming

I have installed the package (or `gem`? Apology I am not familiar with proper Ruby terminology) to an alternative location by running the `setup` script in the github repo:

```
./script/setup --path ../bin
```

I can see that the main script `terraforming` has been installed under `bin`. The path is `bin/ruby/2.3.0/bin/terraforming` in this case.

However when I ran it, I got this error:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:241:in
>   `bin_path': can't find gem terraforming (>= 0.a)
>   (Gem::GemNotFoundException)   from
>   ../bin/ruby/2.3.0/bin/terraforming:22:in`'

What is the proper way to invoke this `terraforming` script from the alternative installation location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may still need to `gem install terraforming` to install the gem.

The `script/setup` only installs dependencies -- you can see in [its code](https://github.com/cmedley/terraforming/blob/master/script/setup) that it just runs `bundle install`, which installs the gems in the included [gemfile](https://github.com/cmedley/terraforming/blob/master/Gemfile). This gemfile does not include the `terraforming` gem itself as it expects you to do this independently.

Comment: From which directory?

Comment: The directory where you run it shouldn't matter, `gem install <gem name>` will install the gem globally on your system.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of application are you using? Rails? Sinatra? Does it have a `gemfile`? If so, you should be able to explicitly set the path to the gem:

```rb
gem 'terraforming', path: '/bin/ruby/2.3.0/bin/terraforming'
```

For a command line utility you need to include the path to the gem using the `$LOAD_PATH`. You can read the [Ruby docs about requiring code](https://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/#requiring-code) or there are other answers on StackOverflow that might be helpful like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671318/understanding-rubys-load-paths) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837123/adding-a-directory-to-load-path-ruby).

Comment: The project is actually a command line utility. I suppose to run it in a shell like `terraforming s3 --profile hoge`. See https://github.com/cmedley/terraforming#prerequisites for details

Comment: if u use bundler to install your gem, you can try using deployment mode provided by it
https://bundler.io/man/bundle-install.1.html#DEPLOYMENT-MODE

in this case, the executable file would be in vendor/bundle/ruby/{version}/bin. In case you need to require it in your code, you need to add it onto the load path as well

Comment: I've updated my answer to include info about using the `$LOAD_PATH` to tell your system about the gem. I think that should get you what you need.

Comment: I read the resources you quoted but I don't find them actionable. I export the LOAD_PATH but the cli still can't run. Same error message.